# Change calling app to browser protocol - macOS?

Tags: macos, web-browser, call

Is there some way to make the default "Calling" app a browser? For example, I use Google Messages web app for calling + texting, through my Microsoft Edge browser. I've got it installed as an "app".

I know that in the FaceTime's preferences, you can change it a macOS app like Zoom or Teams. But I'd love it if I can default to Edge, or more specifically the "app" I made for Google Messages.

Thanks for any guideance, and if this isn't possible too, no worries!

- [Here's more details](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/install-manage-or-uninstall-apps-in-microsoft-edge-0c156575-a94a-45e4-a54f-3a84846f6113) on making a website an app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to do that using [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps)

It installs itself as a System Settings panel where you can control the default apps for any URI scheme.

The default app for calling is the one that handles the `tel:` scheme. There's also the `sms:` scheme if you want to change the default messaging app.

[image: settings pane for SwiftDefaultApps]

The app set as default needs to already have implemented a handler for that type of URI, otherwise this won't work. It's possible that Google Messages might already have that handler, but if it does not, you can't do anything to fix it.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I tried it out and Edge was able to recognize the app as a calling handler, and it opened Messages. The only thing it can't do (which doesn't surprise me) is automatically go to the "Phone" tab and dial the call. That's fine, at least it gets me to the app I use.

I'll definitely  this app/repo for other use cases. Thanks again!